# What is the better way to ident a big array for example in javascript? (General Formatting Rules)

Tags: javascript, formatting, rules

What is the better way to ident (according to General Formatting Rules) a big array like this:

```
let bigArray = ["3d_rotation","fingerprint","delete","delete",
                "bug_report","extension","extension","android",
                "card_giftcard","fingerprint","face","face",
                "card_giftcard","3d_rotation","android","bug_report"];
```

Comment: How do you want to format this array? What you mean when say 'according to General Formatting Rules'?

Comment: Other than perhaps to make code readable there are no hard and fast formatting rules. It's a personal/team decision and one that we can't really answer. What you should do is invest in a good linter like eslint and copy the rules from project to project so that your code formatting is standardised.

Comment: Why is that array in the code at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this can vary by your employer in the real world. In this situation, I would anyway use 4 lines.

I discovered a site that can help on this stuffs: http://jsbeautifier.org/.

jsBeautifier is easy to use and a useful tool for fixing indentation issues. At work, I set up automated tools like linters to resolve my indentation.